# nginx check if *.pdf file exists in folder

Tags: nginx

I think I have a problem understanding how I can check if a file exists in a specific folder with nginx.

for example, I use this url:

[www.domain.tld/folder/filename.pdf](http://www.domain.tld/folder/filename.pdf)

now, I think I have to check it like that:

```
location /folder/.(pdf)$ {
    
}
```

is that correct?

and then, if it is the right way, how can I redirect if the file doesn't exists?
I'm new and from apache os it is a bit hard for men to switch in my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) matches the requested URI, but does not decide if the file exists. The contents of the `location` block determines the action if the file exists or not, and the simplest way to accomplish that is using `try_files`.

The [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) will test if the file exists and internally redirect to another URI if it does not.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/folder/.*\.pdf$ {
    try_files $uri /another/uri;
}
```